# Google Chrome save visited links

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I want to save my browsing history, but it looks like Google Chrome isn't really concerned about browsing history. As far as i know it deletes history older than a month, and when i look in chrome://history it won't even automatically load the next page. WTF? I've used chrome for years and i like it, but that's pretty ridiculous. It also can't save history at all as a csv/txt file.

Now i've been searching for a while for something simple that just stores 2 values:

time stamp - visited link

For EVERY link that i open, and could save it as a .csv file

But i can't really find anything.. hopefully anybody here can help me out? Would be great if it's just an extension for Chrome...

Comment: I have configured Chrome to never delete my history, likewise, I have my history since I started using chrome over 5 years ago.  So your conclusion about Chrome isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Web History](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-let-google-watch-over-your-web.html) can be set up to track things other than just your search activity.

[Signing in to Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/signin.html) brings your bookmarks, history, and other settings to all your devices. Anything you update on one device instantly updates everywhere else, and your Chrome stuff is safe in case anything happens to your computer.